# Having a machine save data on Raspberry Pi 0 W and accessing it over WiFi network

Tags: wifi, usb, pi-zero

This is my first attempt at creating something with Raspberry Pi 0, so I am very sorry if this question does not meet the standard Stack Exchange etiquette. I have a production line with a USB port. When I plug a normal USB stick in it, the data related to the line performance (speed, reject rate and so on) are saved onto the USB stick in a CSV.

My Raspberry Pi 0 W (that is connected to the WiFi on the production floor) will be plugged into the USB port of the machine. I want the production data to be saved, and I want to be able to access the data over the network. So far this is the link that comes closest, but I am not sure if it will work (https://magpi.raspberrypi.org/articles/pi-zero-w-smart-usb-flash-drive).

How would I do this?

Comment: This question is typical of many on this site - asking for a complex hardware/software solution. At least you have defined the overall task, although this is short on actual detail. If I was going to do a project like this I would first setup the Pi as a USB gadget to see if it is even feasible to capture the data. The link you quoted would seem like a viable start. Then you could study the options for transporting the data.

Comment: Thank you, I will follow the instructions till step 10 and come back to this,

Comment: Welcome to Raspberry Pi :-) But as Milliways already noted your question is too broad. Such questions are flagged (look at the close link beneath the question) and may be closed (at 5 votes). This site isn't made for brainstorming and discuss general issues. It is made to do one specific question that can be answered detailed. Please take the short [Tour](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit the [Help Center](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help) to get an idea how things work here. We like to help you :)